# Embed a piece of HTML code or Javascript script inside webview in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, embed, android-webview

I got a small piece of Javascript and HTML code of a table containing statistics that I want to embed into a WebView in my android app. How do i go about doing that. Can someone suggest me with an example and sample code. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create the html page and put the asset folder and load the html page in webview.

using this code:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: i got a piece of code in string how to run in android without webview

Answer (score 4):

```
  WebView webView;

String htmlPre = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body style='margin:0; pading:0; background-color: black;'>";  
    String htmlCode = 
            " <embed style='width:100%; height:100%' src='http://www.platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/1.0/FLVPlayer.swf?fullscreen=true&video=http://www.platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/pl-600.flv&autoplay=true' " +
            "  autoplay='true' " +
            "  quality='high' bgcolor='#000000' " +
            "  name='VideoPlayer' align='middle'" + // width='640' height='480' 
            "  allowScriptAccess='*' allowFullScreen='true'" +
            "  type='application/x-shockwave-flash' " +
            "  pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' />" +
            "";
    String htmlPost = "</body></html>";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", htmlPre+htmlCode+htmlPost, "text/html", "UTF-8", null); 

}
```

above example use the html code in webView.

Comment: does this require us to add INTERNET permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: and add the webview propetywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
   
      webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
      webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
      webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
      webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(webView.getSettings().LOAD_NO_CACHE);

Comment: see this link use the javascript[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the `HTML` in assets and then display it in `WebView` like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

where `webView` is your *`WebView` object* and `index.html` is your *`html` source file*.

Comment: Pleasure... Don't forget to accept the answer which was most helpful !